# What's the best way to count alphanumeric words?

Tags: python, alphanumeric

I am trying to find the best way to count alphanumeric words without using regex and here is what i've done.

```
for line in csv:
        total_lines += 1
        total_words = len(line.split())
        line_char_count =  sum(map(str.isalnum, line.split()))
        line_details.append("Line %d has %d Alphanumeric word/s" % (total_lines, line_char_count))

for line in line_details:
print (line)
```

Instead of counting the alphanumeric words, it excludes the alphanumeric words and counts the non-alphanumeric words. So i tried another approach:

```
for line in csv:
        total_lines += 1
        total_words = len(line.split())
        line_char_count =  sum(map(str.isalnum, line.split()))
        count = total_words - line_char_count
        line_details.append("Line %d has %d Alphanumeric word/s" % (total_lines, count))

for line in line_details:
print (line)
```

I deducted the line_char_count from the total words of the string. Now, it gives me a close answer but punctuation is still counted. I don't know what's the best way to strip of punctuation.
Or if you have better way to count alphanumeric words, please help me.
Thank you

Comment: This is hard to answer as it's not clear what you mean by a alphanumeric word. For example, does the word count if it's surrounded in quotation marks? Because that's not strictly alphanumeric. Does it count if the word has an apostrophe? Is it one or two words if you write "light-hearted"?

Comment: The solutions using the `split()` approach miss counting the last words of sentences because of the period is probably the most obvious flaw in that approach. Aside from the cases Ted already noted. Also you probably want to count words separated by many other characters, like a slash "animals/pets".. list goes on.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Alphanumeric like      l8ter, 2go, 2night,    something like that

Comment: @Todd oh so i should really exclude punctuation marks. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This was written under assumption that "word" is any string of non-whitespace characters:

```
for i, line in enumerate(csv, 1):
    alnum_words = sum(1 for word in line.split() if word.isalnum())
    line_details.append("Line %d has %d Alphanumeric word/s" % (i, alnum_words))
```

Comment: This doesn't count words ending with a period or comma as it'll count the word as non-alphanumeric.

Comment: Yep. The question is whether it is what OP wanted. OTOH, if not, then what **is** a "non-alphanumeric word"?  For example, is `xxx-yyy` a non-alphanumeric word or two words separated by punctuation?

Answer (score 0):

*A regular expression would probably be the best approach. But anyway...*

**This is not a regular expression solution**

This implementation assumes that any character or sequence of characters within the alphanumeric `set` are counted as one word. So, for instance, it would count things like identifier names in blocks of code.

Words are counted separately that are separated by any non-alphanumeric character; spaces, tabs, semicolons and slashes for instance. If you want to count words with apostrophes or hyphens in them as one - add those to the set of `chars`.

```
>>> chars = set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
...             'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
...             '0123456789'
...             '_')     # Underscores to match identifiers?
...             # "-'")    Are these separators or parts of a word?
...
>>> def count_alphanum_words(s):
...     w = False
...     count = 0
...     for ch in s:
...         if ch in chars:
...             w = True
...         else:
...             if w:
...                 count += 1
...                 w = False
...     if w:
...         count += 1
...     return count
...     
>>> count_alphanum_words("Th3 qu1ck 8r0wn f0x jump3d 0v3r th3 l4zy d0g.")
9
>>> line_details = []
>>> for n, line in enumerate(csv, 1):
...     count = count_alphanum_words(line)
...     line_details.append("Line %d has %d Alphanumeric words" % (n, count))
...
>>> for line in line_details:
...     print(line)
```

The algorithm should be quick since it only incurs one pass through the characters on a line to get the word count. Other approaches using `split()` incur one pass to do the splits, then another pass to process the list of items it produces, plus iteration over the chars of individual words to determine if they're alphanumeric.

However, the solutions with `split()` and `isalnum()` perform more operations in native code. So the difference in performance times of this code against the other solutions is negligible. The other solutions may not correctly count the words though.

Comment: `regex` would have been the perfect solution but the question says without `regex`

Comment: Alright... I'll come up with another way and update this.

Comment: Thank you @Todd this is a very nice explanation but  as much as possible no regex. Thank you again

Comment: This solution doesn't use regex!! @Ajedrez it uses a set. that is not a regex.

Answer (score -1):

is this what you want?

```
line = "Rolls-Royce Motor Cars Inc. said it expects its U.S. sales to remain steady at about 1,200 cars in 1990"   
line_char =  sum(i.isalnum() for i in line.split())

print(line_char)
```

Output: 15

Comment: The OP wanted to count words, not characters.